# Angular2: pass function as argument in view to prepare object

Tags: angular

I don't know I say it correctly in the title but here is what I wanted to do. Please suggest alternative if possible or how can I do this.

`<button (click)="setObject({date_rec: new Date(), topicString: getTopic(topicId)}" class="btn btn-default">mybuttun</button>`

or

`<button (click)="setObject({date_rec: newDatePipe, topicString: array | getTopicStringPipe}" class="btn btn-default">mybuttun</button>`

I know I can achieve this in the component logic but my object property name is dynamic. I want to set it in view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your issue as: `getTopic(topicID)` is being executed / invoked instead of returning a reference to `getTopic(topicID) as typeof function`.

To solve this, your need to `return` a reference to the function.You could do this a couple ways...

**Option 1**

Pass a second object as a param containing the params for the function your are passing.

```
<button (click)="setObject({date_rec: new Date(), topicString: getTopic, {params: [topicId]}}" class="btn btn-default">mybuttun</button>
```

**Option 2**

Return the function via an anonymous funciton execution.

```
<button (click)="setObject({date_rec: new Date(), topicString: ()=>{return ()=>{getTopic(topicId);}}}" class="btn btn-default">mybuttun</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I chose your option one!

Comment: @praHoc glad I could help!